# Sitecore Leprechaun giving error while generating models (Sitecore 10.1)

Tags: leprechaun

We are using a fresh Sitecore 10 instance in local and trying to set up Leprechaun for generating C# class for respective template and serialization of Sitecore Items under Visual studio solution.

- Placed config file under "src" folder `- \src\Leprechaun.config`
- Placed `*.*.module.json` under `src\Feature\PageContent\Feature.PageContent.module.json`

  ```
    <configurations import="**\*.module.json">
    <!--
        Base code generation configuration.
        Use this abstract configuration to override the <defaults> where needed.
        (leave defaults alone to make config upgrades simpler)
    -->
    <configuration name="DemoSite.Helix" abstract="true">
        <codeGenerator scripts="$(configDirectory)\Scripts\Glassmapper.csx" outputFile="$(configDirectory)\$(layer)\$(module)\code\$(layer).$(module).Model.cs" />
        <typeNameGenerator type="Leprechaun.MetadataGeneration.StandardTypeNameGenerator, Leprechaun" singleInstance="true" namespaceRootPath="/sitecore/templates/$(layer)/$(module)" keepLeadingUnderscores="false" />
        <templatePredicate rootNamespace="DemoSite.$(layer).$(module).Templates">
            <include name="Templates" path="$(layer)/$(module)" />
        </templatePredicate>
    </configuration>
    <configuration name="DemoSite.Base" abstract="true">
        <codeGenerator scripts="$(configDirectory)\Scripts\Glassmapper.csx" outputFile="$(configDirectory)\$(layer)\$(module)\code\$(layer).$(module).Model.cs" />
        <typeNameGenerator type="Leprechaun.MetadataGeneration.StandardTypeNameGenerator, Leprechaun" singleInstance="true" namespaceRootPath="/sitecore/templates/$(layer)/DemoSite/$(module)" keepLeadingUnderscores="false" />
        <templatePredicate rootNamespace="DemoSite.$(layer).$(module).Templates">
            <include name="Templates" path="$(layer)/PennFoster/$(module)" />
        </templatePredicate>
    </configuration>

    <configuration name="DemoSite.Scaffolding.Base" abstract="true">
        <codeGenerator scripts="$(configDirectory)\Scripts\Glassmapper.csx" outputFile="$(configDirectory)\Foundation\Scaffolding\code\$(module).Scaffolding.Model.cs" />
        <typeNameGenerator type="Leprechaun.MetadataGeneration.StandardTypeNameGenerator, Leprechaun" singleInstance="true" namespaceRootPath="/sitecore/templates/$(layer)/$(module)" keepLeadingUnderscores="false" />
        <templatePredicate rootNamespace="$(module).Foundation.Scaffolding.$(module)Templates" />
    </configuration>
  ```

  ```
  {
  "namespace": "Feature.PageContent",
  "items": {
    "includes": [
      {
        "name": "Projects.Feature.PageContent.Templates",
        "allowedPushOperations": "createUpdateAndDelete",
        "database": "master",
        "maxRelativePathLength": "120",
        "scope": "itemAndDescendants",
        "path": "/sitecore/templates/Feature/DemoSite/PageContent"
      },
      {
        "name": "Projects.Feature.PageContent.Renderings",
        "path": "/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/PageContent",
        "allowedPushOperations": "createUpdateAndDelete",
        "database": "master",
        "maxRelativePathLength": "120",
        "scope": "itemAndDescendants"
      }
    ]
  },
  "leprechaun": {
    "configuration": {
      "@extends": "DemoSite.Helix",
      "@name": "Feature.PageContent"
    }
  }
  }
  ```

When we run command `"dotnet leprechaun /c "C:\Source\Demo\DemoSite\src\Leprechaun.config"`
we are getting below exception -

```
Unhandled exception. Configy.Containers.MicroResolutionException: Cannot activate Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore.Filters.SitecoreTemplatePredicate, constructor param 'leprechaunModuleFactory' (LeprechaunModuleFactory). The type 'LeprechaunModuleFactory' is probably not registered, or may need to be an explicit unmapped parameter (as an XML attribute on the type registration). Inner message: Cannot construct Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Filesystem.Formatting.Yaml.YamlSerializationFormatter because it has > 1 public constructor.
   at Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Activate(Type type, KeyValuePair`2[] unmappedConstructorParameters)
   at Configy.XmlContainerBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<RegisterConfigTypeInterface>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Resolve(Type type)
   at Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Resolve[T]()
   at Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore.SitecoreOrchestrator.GetTemplates(IContainer configuration) in D:\a\1\s\src\Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore\SitecoreOrchestrator.cs:line 54
   at Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore.SitecoreOrchestrator.GetAllTemplates(IEnumerable`1 configurations) in D:\a\1\s\src\Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore\SitecoreOrchestrator.cs:line 43
   at Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore.SitecoreOrchestrator.GenerateMetadata(IContainer[] configurations) in D:\a\1\s\src\Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore\SitecoreOrchestrator.cs:line 26
   at Leprechaun.Execution.Runner.GenerateMetadata(IOrchestrator orchestrator, LeprechaunConfigurationBuilder configuration) in D:\a\1\s\src\Leprechaun\Execution\Runner.cs:line 123
   at Leprechaun.Execution.Runner.Run(IRuntimeArgs parsedArgs) in D:\a\1\s\src\Leprechaun\Execution\Runner.cs:line 34
   at Leprechaun.Cli.Program.Run(ConsoleArgs parsedArgs, CommandLineParser argsParser) in D:\a\1\s\src\Leprechaun.Cli\Program.cs:line 54
   at Leprechaun.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\src\Leprechaun.Cli\Program.cs:line 28
```

Comment: @ben-lipson , We followed the suggestion on given article but getting some error while generating code

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your full Leprechaun.config file or knowing the version of Leprechaun, I can't say for certain. However, I believe the problem is the `<serializationFormatter>` section towards the bottom.

The `type` for the latest version of Leprechaun *should* be:

`Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore.YamlSerializationFormatterWrapper, Leprechaun.InputProviders.Sitecore`.

I *suspect* you have it set to the previous version (for Sitecore CLI 3.0) which was:

`Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Filesystem.Formatting.Yaml.YamlSerializationFormatter, Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client`.

Sitecore CLI made some changes with 4.0 which weren't backwards compatible with Leprechaun.

I recommend whenever upgrading Leprechaun, please compare your `Leprechaun.config` against the one from the GitHub repo that's tagged with the same version.